# Como codificar todo un archivo php en BASE64

Tags: php

tengo el siguiente problema.

Desarrollé un programa en PHP para varios clientes este programa se debe instalar en un wamp de forma local con el cliente, puesto que se conecta con un SQL SERVER de un software de un tercero, un mayorista se ofreció a distribuirlo, se me ocurrió sacar el concentrado de PHP al que llamo base.php que contiene todas las funciones en POO para mi programa, la idea es que cuando el mayorista lo instale introduzca un numero de serie y envié un formulario a mi servidor donde verificaré si el numero de serie es correcto luego, daré una respuesta con el archivo base.php en BASE64 el problema es que no se como codificar todo el contenido del archivo php en una exhibición, se puede? hay paginas donde pongo todo mi php en un formulario y lo codifica pero al recibir el numero de serie lo almacenaré en una constante, luego lo codifico y lo regreso, al menos esa es la idea.

Answer (score 1):

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

la próxima intenta buscar; en éste caso con buscar algo como "php base64" hubieses encontrado ese mismo enlace.

Entre los comentarios tienes un montón de ejemplos.

Comment: Si, estoy familiarizado con la función pero no puedo meter todo el php dentro por los errores de sintaxis

Comment: No entiendo a que te refieres con "errores de sintaxis". Si le pasas a esa función los fuentes (el contenido del fichero de texto) del código PHP que quieres enviar se códificará como cualquier otra cadena de texto. Si tiene errores de sintaxis (aparte de lo evidente: corrigelos) no afectarán a la codificación en base64, pero no funcionará en destino, claro. De todas formas quizá deberías plantearte si ésta es la mejor forma de proceder; enviar código PHP y ejecutarlo en destino es un agujero de seguridad considerable.